# Force Federated Authentication redirection from an Exception Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an Asp.net MVC application that uses WSFederationAuthentication to manage authentication.  I make a series of calls within a controller action and those calls can result in the need to authenticate again.  Right now, when I determine that I need to re-authenticate I throw an UnauthorizedAccessException.

I've implemented an ExceptionFilter for the controller that catches this UnauthroizedAccessException and returns a 401.  Here's the code:

```
public void OnException(System.Web.Mvc.ExceptionContext context)
{
    if (context.Exception is UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        context.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult("Login again.");
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the Federated Authentication HttpModule doesn't redirect this request to the STS.  The user just receives a 401 error.  Is the ExceptionFilter too late in the pipeline to return the 401?  Is there another way to force the user to authenticate again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect user to login page if `UnauthroizedAccessException` has occurred:

```
public void OnException(System.Web.Mvc.ExceptionContext context)
{
    if (context.Exception is UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        // Redirect to login page again

        // 1
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
        new RouteValueDictionary {{ "Controller", "YourController" },
                                  { "Action", "YourAction" } });
        // 2
       Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
       if (controller != null)
       {
           filterContext.Cancel = true;
           controller.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("./Login");
       }

        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
    base.OnException(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because "this" isn't a controller.  The ExceptionFilter is implemented as its own class and RedirectToAction doesn't appear to be available.

Comment: I went with #1 above.  Worked great.  Thanks!